# How can I unhide an image when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make appear an image when my button is clicked? Here  is the current HTML and CSS I have.

HTML:

```
<div id="Button"><button type="button">Deck of the week!</button></div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
background-color: Transparent;
border: 10px;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: "Dense Regular";
```

I have done research and I understand I need to unhide an image using several CSS and JavaScript elements, any help?

Comment: So you have "done research" which revealed that you need to use CSS and JavaScript "elements", but yielded no actual code examples? Can you share with us the sites you researched? By the way, the CSS is your question is broken; it is missing the final brace. It is also formatted/indented poorly.

Comment: Hi, I missed it when copy pasting it into here I can assure you I have it. Thank you for your time tho, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="hide()">Deck of the week!</button>
<img src="Screenshot%20(5).png" id="pic" width="100px" height="100px" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Javscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide() {
  var c = document.getElementById("pic"); 
  c.setAttribute("style","visibility:visible")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <button id="Button" href="#">Show/Hide</button>
    <image id="image" src="yourImagePathHere"></image>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById('Button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
    imageElement.style.display = imageElement.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer not to encourage beginners to manipulate styles directly on DOM elements. I'd prefer to write code like `button.addEventLIstener('click', function() { image.classList.toggle('hide'); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="hide()">Make Visible!</button>       
        <img src="Screenshot%20(5).png" id="pic" width="100px" height="100px" style="visibility:hidden"/>
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function hide() {
            var c = document.getElementById("pic");
            c.setAttribute("style","visibility:visible")
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is many ways to do this.

Heres without jquery

Html

```
<img src="image.png" id="image" style="display: none" />

<div id="Button"><button type="button" onclick="click()">Deck of the week!</button></div>
```

javascript

```
function click() {
    getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<div id="Button"><button>Click Me!</button></div>
<img src="image.jpg" id="image" style="display: none" />
```

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $("#button").click(function() {

        $('#image').css({display:'block'});

       });

      });
```